# GroupBy either of two properties in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I know its easy to group objects by two properties but I was wondering is it possible to Group by either of two properties? Probably below example will make it more clear:-

Suppose I have this table:-

```
CategoryID        Fruit
-------------------------
1                 Apple
1                 Grapes
2                 Tablet
2                 Laptop
5                 Coke
6                 Coke
```

Now, i want to group this data either if CategoryIds are same or Fruits are same.

Sample Output:-

```
Group 1:-
1          Apple
1          Grapes

Group 2:-
2          Tablet
2          Laptop

Group 3:-
5          Coke
6          Coke
```

Comment: What if item would get into two groups, e.g. `2 - Coke` in your example?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Then CategoryID group should be preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add some details to your requirements it seems that you want to do a normal group by on `CategoryID`. Then, if any groups only contain a single element you want these to be grouped by `Fruit`. The key of this group will have to contain both a `CategoryID` and a `Fruit`. For groups 1 and 2 in your sample data the `Fruit` property will be the default value for `Fruit`. For group 3 the `CategoryID` will be the default value for `CategoryID`.

You can perform this computation by doing two nested groupings and then unwrapping the inner grouping again:

```
var groupedItems = items
  .GroupBy(item => item.CategoryID)
  .GroupBy(
    inner => inner.Count() > 1
      ? new { CategoryID = inner.Key, Fruit = default(String) }
      : new { CategoryID = default(Int32), inner.First().Fruit }
  )
  .Select(
    outer => outer.Count() == 1
      ? new { outer.Key, Items = outer.First().ToList() }
      : new { outer.Key, Items = outer.Select(inner => inner.First()).ToList() }
  );
```

Given this input

```
var items = new[] {
  new { CategoryID = 1, Fruit = "Apple" },
  new { CategoryID = 1, Fruit = "Coke" },
  new { CategoryID = 2, Fruit = "Tablet" },
  new { CategoryID = 2, Fruit = "Coke" },
  new { CategoryID = 5, Fruit = "Coke" },
  new { CategoryID = 6, Fruit = "Coke" }
};
```

you get this output

```
Key             |Items
----------------+-----------------
CategoryId Fruit|CategoryID Fruit
----------------+-----------------
1          null |1          Apple
                |1          Coke
----------------+-----------------
2          null |2          Tablet
                |2          Coke
----------------+-----------------
0          Coke |5          Coke
                |6          Coke
----------------+-----------------
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! I was basically looking to group by either CategoryID or Fruits(Whichever matches in the list), and not grouping just by CategoryID. But, the query which you provided is grouping correctly and I am getting the correct output. Thanks.